# Tabulator Group with empty / null group field values -> no grouping

Tags: javascript, tabulator

In this fiddle with a grouped column 'gender'

https://jsfiddle.net/hpyozw21/5/

```js
var data  = [
     {id:1, name:"Oli Bob NO GENDER CHECK", progress:12, rating:1, col:"red", dob:"", car:1, lucky_no:5},
       {id:101, name:"Oli Bob NULL CHECK", progress:12, gender: null, rating:1, col:"red", dob:"", car:1, lucky_no:5}, 
     {id:2, name:"Mary May", progress:1, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true, lucky_no:10},
     {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", progress:42, gender:"female", rating:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true", lucky_no:12},
     {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", progress:100, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980", lucky_no:18},
     {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", progress:16, gender:"female", rating:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999", lucky_no:33},
     {id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", progress:38, gender:"male", rating:4, col:"red", dob:"12/05/1966", car:1, lucky_no:2},
     {id:7, name:"Jamie Newhart", progress:23, gender:"male", rating:3, col:"green", dob:"14/05/1985", car:true, lucky_no:63},
     {id:8, name:"Gemma Jane", progress:60, gender:"female", rating:0, col:"red", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true", lucky_no:72},
     {id:9, name:"Emily Sykes", progress:42, gender:"female", rating:1, col:"maroon", dob:"11/11/1970", lucky_no:44},
     {id:10, name:"James Newman", progress:73, gender:"male", rating:5, col:"red", dob:"22/03/1998", lucky_no:9},
     {id:11, name:"Martin Barryman", progress:20, gender:"male", rating:5, col:"violet", dob:"04/04/2001"},
     {id:12, name:"Jenny Green", progress:56, gender:"female", rating:4, col:"indigo", dob:"12/11/1998", car:true},
     {id:13, name:"Alan Francis", progress:90, gender:"male", rating:3, col:"blue", dob:"07/08/1972", car:true},
     {id:14, name:"John Phillips", progress:80, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"green", dob:"24/09/1950", car:true},
     {id:15, name:"Ed White", progress:70, gender:"male", rating:0, col:"yellow", dob:"19/06/1976"},
     {id:16, name:"Paul Branderson", progress:60, gender:"male", rating:5, col:"orange", dob:"01/01/1982"},
     {id:17, name:"Gemma Jane", progress:50, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"red", dob:"14/04/1983", car:true},
     {id:18, name:"Emma Netwon", progress:40, gender:"female", rating:4, col:"brown", dob:"07/10/1963", car:true},
     {id:19, name:"Hannah Farnsworth", progress:30, gender:"female", rating:1, col:"pink", dob:"11/02/1991"},
     {id:20, name:"Victoria Bath", progress:20, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"purple", dob:"22/03/1986"},
     ];

var columns = [
          {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150, editable:true},
          {title:"Progress", field:"progress", sorter:"number", align:"left", formatter:"progress", width:200,  editable:true},
          {title:"Gender", field:"gender", editable:true},
          {title:"Rating", field:"rating",  formatter:"star", align:"center", width:100, editable:true},
          {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", align:"center", sorter:"date", editable:true},
          {title:"Driver", field:"car", align:"center", editable:true, formatter:"tickCross"},
      ]

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
 index:"pid",
  height: '100%',
  layout: "fitData",
 columns: columns,
  data: data,  
  groupBy:"gender"
});
```

```html
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

I would like to have the rows with id 1 and 101 (the ones with the gender deleted or null) on the root level of the table with no grouping.
Is that somehow possible? This means if the value of the grouped field is null or undefined the row should be not grouped at the root of the table.

Thanks a lot!
Martin

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, once grouping is enabled all rows must be contained in a group